# Firemonkey - Showing a image from base64 string (how to?)

Tags: android, ios, delphi, firemonkey

I am creating a *FMX applicacion* (Delphi Seattle) for android/ios and I am receiving *Json* data through *RESTResponse* component. The json data has an Image (Photo) field in `base64 (utf8 encoded)` string that I would like to show in a TImage component. Please can you show me how can i do that?

**UPDATE**: I have already the JSON data as an object and as a string like this:

```
{
   "Name" : "Alfred", 
   "Photo": "zC8bH24CIjYX5eedCWIvnNqar4xkQRqPxt2n8cReAwWD4+w/2qErkJggg==..."
}
```

So i have the Image in a base64 string. So my real questions would be:

1. How to convert the base64 string into an image?
2. How to show the image in a TImage component?

I am learning delphi, and trying to figure out by myself it's a difficult, so i appreciate your help with this.

Thanks.

Comment: First of all, are you already using a JSON parser? Once you have that, then it's a matter of decoding this string.

Comment: ...although this is a rather unfocused question.  Which part is the question? There are at least three questions here.  How to decode JSON and retrieve the base64 string?  How to decode the base64 string to an image?  How to show an image in a TImage?  If you have three separate questions, then ask them in separate questions.  If the first and third question you know how to do, then they are irrelevant and should not be included here.

Comment: We aren't here to do your work for. Please explain which specific aspect you are finding hard and then we'll find you a duplicate question to help.

Comment: You also give no information about *has an Image field*. What is that **specifically**? How did the data get in there and what is the format that we will get after the Base64 decode?

Comment: To all, please see my updated question.

Answer (score 4):

You are asking three separate questions:

1. how to extract the base64 from the JSON.  Any JSON parser will handle that, including the [one built in to Delphi](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/JSON).
2. how to decode the base64.  Base64 is a very easy algorithm to implement by hand, it doesn't take much code to do it.  But there are also plenty of ready-made implementations available.  For example, Indy ships pre-installed with Delphi, and has a `TIdDecoderMIME` class for decoding base64 data into a string, byte array, or `TStream`.  In this case, you could use `TIdDecoderMIME.DecodeStream()` to decode the base64 into a `TMemoryStream`.
3. how to display the decoded image in a `TImage`.  In FireMonkey, all image formats are handled by the [`FMX.Graphics.TBitmap`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Graphics.TBitmap) class, which has a [`LoadFromStream()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Graphics.TBitmap.LoadFromStream) method (see Embarcadero's documentation on the [Supported Image Formats](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/FMX.Graphics.TBitmapCodecManager#Supported_Image_Formats) that `TBitmap` can handle on each platform).  So, in this case, you would call `TImage.Bitmap.LoadFromStream()` passing it the stream from step #2 above.

So, you can try something like this:

```
uses
  ..., JSON, IdCoderMIME;

var
  S: String;
  Strm: TMemoryStream;
begin
  S := (RESTResponse1.JSONValue as TJSONObject).Values['Photo'].Value;
  Strm := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    TIdDecoderMIME.DecodeStream(S, Strm);
    Strm.Position := 0;
    Image1.Bitmap.LoadFromStream(Strm);
  finally
    Strm.Free;
  end;
end;
```